# get and check javascript array of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a dynamic object which will add new object and update existing array. I need to check below question

1. wheather array has another array?
2. how to get data from array of array ?

below is the array object

```
[
"Stories",
"Tasks",
"In Progress",
"In Review",
"Completed",
[
    {
        "divName": "content-container2",
        "content": "us 2345",
        "topPos": 109,
        "leftPos": 150
    },
    {
        "divName": "content-container3",
        "content": "Description",
        "topPos": 98,
        "leftPos": 382
    },
    {
        "divName": "content-container4",
        "content": "12212",
        "topPos": 110,
        "leftPos": 644
    }
]
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: *isArray* functions commonly include `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]'`. Maybe that's a start to working out if a member is an array or not?

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: @JoeMoe1984 It is a problem which could be found in many projects, so it doesn't matter if it's a homework.

Answer (score 1):

I'm addressing what I understood & what I know

I don't know if there are any inbuilt functions are there, you can iterate over array and get your answers.

```
Ques:- wheather array has another array?
```

You can use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this like bellow.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,[1,2,3],5]
arr.some(function(element){
     return Array.isArray(element)
 })// returns true
```

it will return `true` if any element will be array.

```
Ques:- how to get data from array of array ?
```

You can use `forEach` and check that if it is an array access the element

```
var arr = [1,2,3,[1,2,3],5];
arr.forEach(function(element){
      if(Array.isArray(element)){
         console.log(element[0])
       }
}); //prints 1
```

If it gives a way to start with it's fine.

**NOTE**:- `Some` & `ForEach` are not supported by IE8. There `for` loop will work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you can use isArray method

```
var arr=/* your array */
var pos=[];
var hasArray=false;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
   if(Array.isArray(arr[i])){
      hasArray=true;
      pos.push(i);
    }
}
// now getting sub arrays
for(var i=0;i<pos.length;i++)
{
   var subArr=arr[pos[i]];
   /* do something with this subarr */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could loop thru the array, check if the element is array as:

```
for( var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    //check if arr[i] is Array
    if(arr[i] instanceof Array) {
        //its array
        var objArr = arr[i];
        //loop thru all objects
        for(var x = 0, xlen= Object.keys(objArr).length; x < xlen; x++) {
            //loop thru object to get all values
            var obj = objArr[x];
            for(var k in obj) {
                console.log( "Key:"+ k + " value:" + obj[k] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzq7neqv/)